# Is there a limit on the number of columns when using the Spark Cassandra connector?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I can connect cassandra from spark but when i try to read cassandra table which has a 1244 column there is a no problem , but when i try to read cassandra table which has a 1245 or higher column count , spark gives me StackOverFlow exception.

Is there a limit value column count in spark? How can i change that?

Err log:

```
>  >>> hosts ={"spark.cassandra.connection.host":'10.0.0.10,10.0.0.11,10.0.0.12',"table":"dummy_table","keyspace":"dummy_keyspace"}
> >>> data_frame=sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(**hosts).load()
> >>> data_frame.show() Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File
> "/home/pc3/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 494, in show
>     print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))   File "/home/pc3/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
> line 1321, in __call__   File
> "/home/pc3/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
>     return f(*a, **kw)   File "/home/pc3/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
> line 326, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
> occurred while calling o52.showString. :
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task serialization failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError
> java.lang.StackOverflowError  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1190)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
```

Comment: please update your post with the full stacktrace

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly note on how to ask good questions. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for answer. I updated post now can you check again ?

Comment: Perhaps you can increase executor stack size by adding something like `.config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-Xss16m")` when you getOrCreate a SparkSession?

Comment: spark = SparkSession.builder.config(‘spark.app.name’, ‘Test’).config(‘spark.master’, ‘local[*]’).config(‘spark.driver.memory’, ‘100g’).config(‘spark.driver.maxResultSize’, ‘500g’).config(‘spark.executer.memory’, ‘10g’).config(‘spark.executer.cores’, ‘1000’)
.config(‘spark.cores.max’, ‘1000’).config(‘spark.python.worker.memory’, ‘10g’).config(‘spark.sql.shuffle.partitions’,1000’).config(‘spark.default.parallelism’,’1000').config(‘spark.debug.maxToStringFields’,‘100’).config(‘spark.executor.extraJavaOptions’, ‘-Xss16m’).getOrCreate()                           **I used like that but didn't run**

Comment: **Also i want to show the other code part at below** hosts="spark.cassandra.connection.host":'10.0.0.10,10.0.0.11,10.0.0.12',"table":"dummy_table","keyspace":"dummy_keyspace"}
data_frame=spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(**hosts).load()

Comment: **.config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-Xss16m")** When i use this command on linux terminal like that **./bin/pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.1.0 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xss16m** it worked. Thanks again.